# Certificate files for SSL connection using ZeosLib and MySql database

Tags: mysql, delphi, ssl

I have basic knowledge in ssl and when executing the connection of an application made in delphi with ZeosLib
in a MySql database, I had a question regarding the certificate. According to information the procedure would
be...

```
CA.Text = c:\mysqlCerts\ca-cert.pem
Cert.Text = c:\mysqlCerts\client-cert.pem
Key.Text = c:\mysqlCerts\client-key.pem

  with ZConnection1 do
  begin
    Connected:= False;
    Database := DB.Text;
    HostName := Host.Text;
    Password := Pass.Text;
    Port     := StrToIntDef(Port.Text,0);
    Protocol := 'mysql-5';
    User     := User.Text;

    if bSSL.Checked then
    begin
      Properties.Values['MYSQL_SSL']:= 'TRUE';
      Properties.Values['MYSQL_SSL_CA']   := CA.Text;
      Properties.Values['MYSQL_SSL_CERT'] := Cert.Text;
      Properties.Values['MYSQL_SSL_KEY']  := Key.Text;
    end;
```

Variable like MYSQL_SSL_CA, MYSQL_SSL_CERT, MYSQL_SSL_KEY is referring to a path on the server or on the local computer? If it's local computer, wouldn't it be exposing the certificate files from a security point of view? Should I copy the certificate files to the client computer?

Comment: If it would be for the server you would need to transmit that config data/information unsecured first - that would kill the whole sense of transfer encryption like TLS aims at. SSL has been dead for years.

Comment: Exactly, it's like encrypting the data and sending the key with the data. This is the reason why I didn't understand this procedure.

Comment: How about [reading/asking at ZeosLib directly](https://zeoslib.sourceforge.io/search.php?keywords=MYSQL_SSL_CERT)? Bonus: if you can do `with ZConnection1 do` then why not applying that shortcut to `Properties`, too?

Answer (score 0):

According to information, you must create a certificate on the client side and a password will be required to complete the connection or else you must enter the certificate data on the client side on the mysql server, as is done with the certificate on the server side and then the connection secure should work, as with https.

https://www.xmodulo.com/enable-ssl-mysql-server-client.html

Comment: "_on the client side on the mysql server_" - what?